# The name 'Grid' does not exist in the current context vs 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I want to make example from this site http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anjudidi/example-of-datagrid-in-Asp-Net/
Here is my code. I made ASP.NET Project from standard. I delete all excep web.config and I made DataGrid.aspx ad DataGrid.aspx.cs.
But error appears The name 'Grid' does not exist in the current contex
and The name 'TextBox1' does not exist in the current contex
I upload project to site 
http://www.sendspace.com/file/40vsjs

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DataGrid.aspx.cs" Inherits="sapnamalik_DataGrid" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:DataGrid ID="Grid" runat="server" PageSize="5" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyField="EmpId"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnPageIndexChanged="Grid_PageIndexChanged" OnCancelCommand="Grid_CancelCommand"
OnDeleteCommand="Grid_DeleteCommand" OnEditCommand="Grid_EditCommand" OnUpdateCommand="Grid_UpdateCommand">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="EmpId" DataField="EmpId">
</asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="F_Name" DataField="F_Name">
</asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="L_Name" DataField="L_Name">
</asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="City" HeaderText="City">
</asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="EmailId" HeaderText="EmailId">
</asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="EmpJoining" HeaderText="EmpJoining">
</asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:EditCommandColumn EditText="Edit" CancelText="Cancel" UpdateText="Update" HeaderText="Edit">
</asp:EditCommandColumn>
<asp:ButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" Text="Delete">
</asp:ButtonColumn>
</Columns>
<FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" Mode="NumericPages" />
<AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" />
<ItemStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:DataGrid>
<br />
<br />
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="lblEmpId" runat="server" Text="EmpId"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="lblfname" runat="server" Text="F_Name"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="lblLname" runat="server" Text="L_Name"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text="City"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="lblEmailId" runat="server" Text="EmailId"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> Q
</td>
<td>
<asp:Label ID="lblEmpJoining" runat="server" Text="EmpJoining"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="btnReset_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="btnOk_Click" />
</div>
<div>
<asp:DataGrid ID="Grid1" runat="server" PageSize="5" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="EmpId" DataField="EmpId"></asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="F_Name" DataField="F_Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="L_Name" DataField="L_Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="City" HeaderText="City"></asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="EmailId" HeaderText="EmailId"></asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="EmpJoining" HeaderText="EmpJoining"> </asp:BoundColumn>
</Columns>
<FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" Mode="NumericPages" />
<AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" />
<ItemStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:DataGrid>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class sapnamalik_DataGrid : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlConnection con;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindData();
        }
    }
    public void BindData()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connect"]);
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Employee";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Grid.DataSource = ds;
        Grid.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
    protected void Grid_PageIndexChanged(object source, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindData();
    }
    protected void Grid_EditCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/631fc0/runtime-table-creation-in-wpf/.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
        BindData();
    }
    protected void Grid_CancelCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid.EditItemIndex = -1;
        BindData();
    }
    protected void Grid_DeleteCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connect"]);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        int EmpId = (int)Grid.DataKeys[(int)e.Item.ItemIndex];
        cmd.CommandText = "Delete from Employee where EmpId=" + EmpId;
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        Grid.EditItemIndex = -1;
        BindData();
    }
    protected void Grid_UpdateCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connect"]);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@F_Name", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@L_Name", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailId", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpJoining", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        cmd.CommandText = "Update Employee set F_Name=@F_Name,L_Name=@L_Name,City=@City,EmailId=@EmailId,EmpJoining=@EmpJoining where EmpId=@EmpId";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        Grid.EditItemIndex = -1;
        BindData();
    }
    protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connect"]);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd;
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Employee (EmpId,F_Name,L_Name,City,EmailId,EmpJoining) values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    protected void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        TextBox3.Text = "";
        TextBox4.Text = "";
        TextBox5.Text = "";
        TextBox6.Text = "";
    }
    protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindData1();
    }
    public void BindData1()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connect"]);
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Employee";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Grid1.DataSource = ds;
        Grid1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the namespace to markup and code. In markup, do this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DataGrid.aspx.cs" Inherits="ASP_Web_Datagrid.sapnamalik_DataGrid" %>
```

in code, wrap the class with namespace:

```
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ASP_Web_Datagrid
{
    public partial class sapnamalik_DataGrid : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindData();

            }
        }
        public void BindData()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connect"]);
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Employee";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Grid.DataSource = ds;
            Grid.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
        protected void Grid_PageIndexChanged(object source, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Grid.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            BindData();
        }
        protected void Grid_EditCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
        http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/631fc0/runtime-table-creation-in-wpf/.EditItemIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
            BindData();
        }
        protected void Grid_CancelCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            Grid.EditItemIndex = -1;
            BindData();
        }
        protected void Grid_DeleteCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connect"]);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            int EmpId = (int)Grid.DataKeys[(int)e.Item.ItemIndex];
            cmd.CommandText = "Delete from Employee where EmpId=" + EmpId;
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            Grid.EditItemIndex = -1;
            BindData();
        }
        protected void Grid_UpdateCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connect"]);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@F_Name", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@L_Name", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailId", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ((TextBox)e.Item.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpJoining", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            cmd.CommandText = "Update Employee set F_Name=@F_Name,L_Name=@L_Name,City=@City,EmailId=@EmailId,EmpJoining=@EmpJoining where EmpId=@EmpId";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            Grid.EditItemIndex = -1;
            BindData();
        }
        protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con;
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connect"]);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Employee (EmpId,F_Name,L_Name,City,EmailId,EmpJoining) values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        protected void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "";
            TextBox2.Text = "";
            TextBox3.Text = "";
            TextBox4.Text = "";
            TextBox5.Text = "";
            TextBox6.Text = "";
        }
        protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindData1();
        }
        public void BindData1()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connect"]);
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Employee";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Grid1.DataSource = ds;
            Grid1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: afzalulh, Thanks but that not work for me. And when I click on button method appears in asp.file not .cs like earlier.

Comment: I rebuild this project from another. I run program and that is odd and need even its own database. I know answer. I need that cs file must be in apx.

Answer (score 0):

ok, sometimes it could be a conflict between public partial class name, check if you inherits correctly, remember it is telling you does not exist in the current context , and if for some reason you copied some code from one page to another, it is much possible you are in a new context.

Good luck.

Comment: Ok. I would check.